# pytest fails to load pytest-mock | VSCode pytest GUI works fine with pytest-mock

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytest, pytest-mock

I try to run unit-tests in python using `pytest`. I have modules `pytest`, `pytest-mock` and `pytest-cov` installed and use VSCode as editor (and I have `conftest.py` file in project root).

When I execute the test cases via VSCode build in functionality, all test cases run through successfully.

However, if I execute the test cases using the build-in terminal using `pytest` command, the unittest with mocked objects are failing.

What is the command VSCode uses to execute the unittests? Did anyone else experience these issues?

If you need further info on settings/setup please let me know.

Highly appreciate any help!